# how to use the for loop result and insert in body email using mailx in perl

Tags: perl

I have this code I wanted to use the result of my for loop `say "$dir,$count";` to be in the body of my email. my attempt is this code `email($dir.$count);` which is wrong.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $email="";
GetOptions("email=s" => \$email);

{
    my $fn = parse_command_line_options();
    my $self = Main->new(
        infile => $fn
    );
    my $dirs = $self->parse_infile();
    for my $dir (@$dirs) {
        my $count = $self->count_files( $dir );
        say "$dir,$count";
    }
}
email($dir.$count);

sub parse_command_line_options {
    my $fn = 'list_dir.txt';
    GetOptions("infile=s" => \$fn ) or die "Error in command line arguments\n";
    return $fn;
}


sub email {
    my $subj = "No of files in outbox folders";
    my $body = "These are the lists of directories with the no of files\n";
    open (MAIL, "|mailx -s \"$subj\" $email");
    print MAIL $body;
    close (MAIL);
}
```

Comment: Well, `$dir` and `$count` aren't in scope when you call `email()`. And `email()` doesn't use any parameter. You need to elaborate on what you are actually trying to do. Send one mail per directory? Or one for all directories with the text you get with `say()` as body? Or ...?

Comment: Or one for all directories with the text you get with say() as body? yes this is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Probably* you are looking for something like

```perl
# ...
{
    my $fn = parse_command_line_options();
    my $self = Main->new(
        infile => $fn
    );
    my @counts;
    my $dirs = $self->parse_infile();
    for my $dir (@$dirs) {
        my $count = $self->count_files( $dir );
        say "$dir,$count";
        push @counts, "$dir,$count"
    }
    email(@counts);
}

# ...

sub email {
    my $subj = "No of files in outbox folders";
    my $body = "These are the lists of directories with the no of files\n";
    open (MAIL, "|mailx -s \"$subj\" $email");
    print MAIL $body, "\n".join(@_);
    close (MAIL);
}
```

Comment: hi @tripleee this works i have minor changes to this `print MAIL join("\n", $body, @_)`

Answer (score 2):

> my attempt is this code `email($dir.$count);` which is wrong.

That's not a very clear way to explain the problems you're seeing. You should tell us why you think it's wrong; what unexpected behaviour you're seeing.

Running your code a compilation check (`perl -c`), I get these errors:

> Global symbol "$dir" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $dir"?) at testit line 22.
> Global symbol "$count" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $count"?) at testit line 22.

But, we can see you **do** declare these variables. So what is wrong here?

You need to learn about "scoping". Not all variables will be visible throughout your program. The section of a program where a variable is visible is known as the variable's scope.

For a variable declared with `my`, the rules are pretty simple. The variable is visible from the point at which it is declared, to the end of the innermost enclosing code block. To explain that, let's look at a section of your code.

```
{
    my $fn = parse_command_line_options();
    my $self = Main->new(
        infile => $fn
    );
    my $dirs = $self->parse_infile();
    for my $dir (@$dirs) {
        my $count = $self->count_files( $dir );
        say "$dir,$count";
    }
}
email($dir.$count);
```

In this section, each pair of matched braces (`{ ... }`) declares a block of code. There's a block that defines the code that is executed each time around the loop and there's another block that is around most of your code (just omitting the call to `email()`).

Your `$count` variable is declared inside the `for` loop. So it is only visible inside that block (it is scoped to that block). The rules for `$dir` are a little more complex. There is a special case for variables that are declared in a `for` loop. They are treated as though they are declared at the start of the loop block at and only visible within that block. It's also worth pointing out that with both of these variables, you get a new instance of the variable each time you go round the loop - so the data in those variables is lost each time a new loop iteration begins.

And that's why Perl says your variables don't exist. It's because they only exist within the loop block, and you are trying to access them outside of that block.

The solution is to either move the declaration of the variables into an outer scope, or you move the call to the subroutine into the `for` block.

A couple of other issues you might come up against having fixed that:

- Do you really mean `email($dir.$count)`? The `.` operator concatenates the two variables. It's possible that you mean `email($dir, $count)` instead.
- You're not actually using the values that you pass to the subroutine.